# Where do I collect revenue?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

As I was running through the first or second memory in Constantinople, I received a notification saying "Revenue Deposit made: xxxx V in the bank vault.

Where do I collect this revenue? I looked around the Assassin HQ and found some chests, but nothing that appeared to be a vault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to renovate one of the banks in the city to be able to collect.  Once in your control, just go to the bank and withdraw your money.

To be able to renovate the bank, you need to be in control of the zone first.  If necessary, you'll have to liberate the templar-held zone first.  The ones in Galata should be available to you in the beginning.  Just examine the sign and pay the required amount.  As you start off, it will cost in the mid-1000's.  But the more renovations you make, the more it will cost.

Comment: And remember that any time you renovate a building it adds about 20% to your awareness meter.  Don't go nuts!